# Sql query over Ignite CacheStore or over database

Tags: sql, caching, ignite

I am a beginner for Ignite, so I have some puzzles, one of which is as follows:when I try to query cache, whether it can look if memory contains or not. If not, then whether it will query database? If not,how to achieve such way?
Please help me if you know.Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries work over in-memory data only. You can either use key access (operations like `get()`, `getAll()`, etc.) and utilize automatic read-through from the persistence store, or manually preload the data before running queries. For information on how effectively load large data set into the cache, see this page: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading

Comment: Thx,Valentin.I have set read-through true,however,it seems that it is not applied.Why?

Comment: In fact,I mean that if my cache stores some Person whose id is smaller than 5 and now I want to query some Person whose id is smaller than 6,but as you can see,cache doesn't stores the Person whose id is 5! So whether Ignite will get the No.5 from database automatically? If not,how to get the No.5 Person?

Comment: Queries do not support read-through, because to automatically load from the database you need to know the set of keys, which you don't know when running the query (you know only some criteria, e.g. id<6). Having said that, you need to make sure that all required data is in cache prior to running queries. On the other hand, if you execute `get()` operation for this ID, the entry will be loaded from the database automatically.

Comment: If I want to query whose id<10,so the Ignite will query over cache and return Persons whose id<5( because my cache only stores such persons). however the user(e.g. Myself) doesn't know whether database stores person whose id is between 5 and 10, so how to get the other persons from database? In other words,if the query over cache returns null objects or less objects,how to make ignite query over database?As you said,make sure that all required data is in cache prior to running queries,but how to make sure that?Load all data from database to cache?I don't think it a good idea.

Comment: If even you don't know what data is stored in your database, why would you expect Ignite to know this? :) You don't have to load *all* the data, `CacheStore.loadCache()` method supports optional parameters which you can use to limit the dataset (refer to the page I provided in the response). Typically, you will load the operational dataset which is currently required for the fast in-memory access, leaving historical data in the database.

Comment: But how to make sure the queryset over cache is all I want to get from database

Comment: @Xijie.Hu  There is no generic solution for that. `loadCache()` allows you to load anything from the database and exact data set depends only on your use case. You need to figure out which data you need to have in memory, estimate its size, set up the appropriate cluster and then load the data. After that you can run queries.

Comment: Now my mind is clearer.Thank you very much for your patience!