# Are read through and sql indexing supported simultaneously?

Tags: ignite

With apache Ignite you have the ability to read-through with a cache http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/persistent-store and also the ability to query a cache via SQL http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/sql-queries.

Are these two features supported simultaneously?  Because Right now i have read-through working.  It makes sense to me, it has a key, if it gets asked for a key that no node knows of then it goes to db.

However the load method is only defined for the primary key, not for any other fields.  Does this mean that its incompatible with read through or there are other methods to implement in order to get the full functionality?

Comment: What do you mean by full functionality?

Comment: I just mean a cache that has read-through and has indexes query able with SQL.  The load method is based on the primary key, not any of the other fields, so how would it be able to query on another field in order to read-through to database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL and read-through can be used simultaneously, but queries will always run only over the data that is in memory. For read-through you need to know the set of keys, so it will work only for key-based access (`get()`, `getAll()`, etc.). For queries you need to preload data manually (using `loadCache()` method, for example).

You can also refer to the discussion here: [Sql query over Ignite CacheStore or over database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571357/sql-query-over-ignite-cachestore-or-over-database)

Comment: Thats what I suspected.  Unless JCache interface offered an opportunity to create arbitrary load methods, I didn't see how it would work.  As far as data lost due to node failures, do you know if Ignite will know to reload keys that were on a lost node upon SQL querying?

Comment: If you lose the data, you will still have to load the data manually before running the queries. I would recommend to use backups to avoid data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use both simultaneously but first you should understand the uses first.

read-through: whenever the data is requested from cache and is not there, Ignite can automatically load it from the underlying database and result is returned to user, and to fetch data you can use methods like `cache.get(key)`, `cache.getAll()`. For more use this link [Data Loading](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading)

SQL queries: First data should be in cache to use SQL queries, and SQL indexing help you to query faster by creating index on that column. For more details you can refer [Query configuration by annotations](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#section-query-configuration-by-annotations)